# Classify text from tab separated columns in text file

Tags: python, bash, python-3.x, filter, classification

I have a text file like [this](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cut):

```
        Education June 2007 Bachelors of Science in
Business Administration ORGANIZATION    ,
University of Phoenix   ORGANIZATION    .

        June 2005 Associate of Arts in
Liberal Arts    ORGANIZATION    ,
Victor Valley Junior College    ORGANIZATION    ,
Victorville LOCATION    ,
CA  LOCATION    .
```

I wanted to retrieve the tab separated first two columns, so I used this:

```
cut -f 1-2 input.txt > output.txt
```

which works fantastic !

Now, I want the the rows which have ORGANIZATION in the second column and contain specific words in the first column i.e. for every row ,if the second column says ORGANIZATION, check if the first column has the word "University","School","College", etc.  , if yes, write it in the output file.

Is there any way to achieve this by modifying the following code or by writing a new one in python ?:

```
cut -f 2-3 input.txt > output.txt
```

The output should look like this:

```
University of Phoenix   ORGANIZATION
Victor Valley Junior College    ORGANIZATION
```

Comment: what is the expected output ? try this may be it help `awk '$2 ~ /ORGANIZATION/ && $1 ~ /University|School/' inputfile`

Comment: Why is this tagged python?

Comment: @PS. - Not working.

Comment: @ChristianW. - If its not do able by modifying this, I would like a python solution.

Comment: You need to add sample output to question to ensure that people answering here are not wasting your and their time.

Comment: @PS. Done. added the output

Comment: If you want a Python solution, you should show us what Python code you have already tried to show us where you are stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 awk -F"/t" '$1 ~ /University|Business/ && $(NF-1) ~ /ORGANIZATION/' as
Business Administration ORGANIZATION    ,
University of Phoenix   ORGANIZATION    .
```

If First column contains either University **OR** Business **AND** last column contains ORGANIZATION then print the line. Here its said last column but its second last column, actual last column is comman/full-stop.

*Here you can change the column number to get the desired result. *This is just `awk` way or writing conditions.*

Comment: Because that column should have "college" in it. Give an example where first column contains "college" and last column contains "ORGANIZATION" and this failed to print the line.

Comment: Doesn't work on this: Victor Valley Junior College    ORGANIZATION. The whole Victor Valley Junior College is first column and ORGANIZATION is separated by tab.

Comment: Because FIRST COLUMN here is "Victor" Not college. College is 4th column.

Comment: Does my comment make sense to you, I don't want to waste your time ?

Comment: it does, I think your input is not properly tab delimited. I may be wrong. try `awk -F $'\t' '{print $1}'` or `awk -v FS=$'\t' '{print $1}'` it will print wrong data.

Comment: Got it : awk -F"/t" '$1 ~ /University|College/ && $(NF-1) ~ /ORGANIZATION/' sample.tsv

Comment: Thanks Man, Please upvote the question if you feel right !

Comment: Any idea how do I only print first and the second column in this ?

Comment: `awk -v FS=$'\t '{print $1,$2}`

Comment: `awk -F"/t" '$1 ~ /University|College/ && $(NF-1) ~ /ORGANIZATION/'{print $1,$2}'`

Comment: Thats not making a difference, This is what im using: awk -F"/t" '$1 ~ /University|College|Academy|Institute|School/ && $(NF-1) ~ /ORGANIZATION/ ' sample.tsv > sample_out.tsv

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed`:

```
cut -f 1-2 file.txt | sed -n '/(Business|University).*ORGANIZATION/p' > output.txt
```

This should match all lines containing Business or University and ORGANIZATION, and print them (`p`).